# Rails has_many :through plus collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was following the Ruby on Rails Guides Active Record Aossications plus some other threads on here, but not sure I'm setting it up right:

Products have many variety image sets (like for color, flavor, style)
A product variety has only one image set (size--> color shirt)

So I think the associations should actually be:

```
Products
--has_many :product_varieties
--has_many :variety_image_sets, through: :product_varieties

Product Varieties
--belongs_to :product
--has_one :variety_image_set

Variety Image Sets
--belongs_to :product_variety
```

I got this setup idea from the Rails Guides example of documents, sections and paragraphs, but unfortunately it only works if I use has_many :variety_image_sets for Product Varieties.

my classes are as follows:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product_category
  has_many :product_varieties
  has_many :variety_image_sets, through: :product_varieties
end

class ProductVariety < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :variety_image_sets
end

class VarietyImageSet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product_variety
end
```

For the Variety Image Set model, I have a product_variety:references in the migration.

I am able to create a Variety Image Set for each individual Product Variety, but I want it to be able to reuse the sets I a product (example, a a black shirt can have several sizes).

Now, moving on to the Collection Select:
Once we have at least one Variety Image Set defined, can use a collection select when creating a new product variety.

This one works:

```
= form_with(model: [@product, product_variety]) do |form|
    = form.collection_select(:variety_image_set_ids, VarietyImageSet.all, :id, :label,  { prompt: true }, {multiple: false})
```

In my controller's product_variety_params:

```
def product_variety_params
  params.require(:product_variety).permit(:size, :unit_amount, :current_inventory, :variety_image_set_ids)
end
```

If I try to change VarietyImageSet.all to variety.variety_image_sets, the select menu goes empty. Also, one Product variety already has one defined, and when I try to assign that one to a different variety, that other variety "steals" it from the first one, instead of both being assigned that variety image set.

Please advise.  Thanks

**UPDATE** Per the suggestion in the first answer, I've updated the associations.  I now create the Variety Image Sets as a nested resource of Product instead of under Product Variety.  This works.

Now, I click on edit for the Product Variety and want to assign a Pariety Image Set to it using the collection_select:

= form.collection_select(:variety_image_sets_id, VarietyImageSet.all, :id, :label,  { prompt: true }, {multiple: false})
with updated params:
def product_variety_params
params.require(:product_variety).permit(:size, :unit_amount, :current_inventory, :variety_image_sets_id)
end

But, I get the error that "Variety Image Set Must Exist".

finally, VarietyImageSet.all will give me all of them, I want to filter them to just those belonging to the product.  @product.variety_image_sets returns undefined method "variety_image_sets" though.

```
= form_with(model: [@product, product_variety]) do |form|
```

[image: ScreenShot of form with error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **ProductVariety** as the middle table with the following association:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product_category
  has_many :product_varieties
  has_many :variety_image_sets, through: :product_varieties
end

class ProductVariety < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :variety_image_sets
end

class VarietyImageSet < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_variety
end
```

Now the **Product** table will have all your products. **VarietyImageSet** will have all varieties for products and the **ProductVariety** table will store which product have which variety.